# Need help clearing the schema cache

Tags: database

I am checking of a particular field type in the schema using:

```
drupal_get_schema('MY_FIELD');
```

I see in the database the field type is int, but when I check after:

```
$schema[$table]['fields']['MY_FIELD']['type']
```

is giving me always 'datetime'.

I assume is a cache issue: I am using:

```
cache_clear_all('schema', 'cache');
```

but still no luck.

Comment: Can you once try `drupal_flush_all_caches()` for clearing the cache from the code.

Comment: What type is it in the _code_?

Comment: @Clive it is always int in the code.

Comment: Ok that makes very little sense - how could the field ever have been a datetime in the database if it's defined as int in the schema? Or are you expecting that by making a change in `hook_schema()` that Drupal will pick that up and adjust the table for you? It won't...

Comment: it make sense that this was 'datetime' before i executed my hook_update_N(). Now it is int everywhere in the database and code but still I get 'datetime' from dpm() function..strange

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different cache entries for the schema, `schema:`, `schema:runtime`, `schema:runtime:1`, and so on.

To clear the lot, try using a wildcard:

```
cache_clear_all('schema', 'cache', TRUE);
```

Comment: thanks this sounds like an answer, my issue is still on, I will come up when I figure it out.